# Write footnote in separate section

Tags: asciidoc

From all examples I can find, Asciidoc's footnote is written inline:

http://www.seinan-gu.ac.jp/~shito/asciidoctor/html_chunk/chap73.html

> The first time you enter a footnote you want to reuse, give it a unique ID in the first position.
>   The next time you reference the footnote you only need to insert the ID in the square brackets

Though it allows referencing footnote by id, but the example only references inline footnote.

How to write a footnote elsewhere, and reference in the main body of text? My footnotes can sometimes be a few paragraphs, so inline makes less sense.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no facility to control footnote positioning. See: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#user-footnotes

If you can live without auto-numbering, you can simulate footnotes using standard Asciidoctor notation:

```
== A section

A bold statement<<myfootnote1,^[1]^>>

== Another section

== Footnotes

[horizontal]
[[myfootnote1]]^1^::
  Express your opinion in a brave way.
```